# Get author Linkedin link

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a posts where the user name and bio appears at the bottom, but I would like to display also the Linkedin link (added already on the user contact info).

I've tried a lot of different ways but I am unable to get it...

I think it would be something like:

`get_the_author_meta( 'user_linkedin' )`

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post some of the code you have tried?  Also, have you tried any LinkedIn plugins for WP?  It appears there might be a few that could help your cause.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally found mu answer here: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be suggested solution on developer.wordpress.org

```
<?php echo nl2br(get_the_author_meta('field_name')); ?>
```

Alternatively Something like this should do the trick

```
<?php echo $author->field_name; ?>
```

To get the author do this on the page

```
<?php $author = get_the_author(); ?>
```

Comment: could you provide code how you added extra field to user. i may be able to help then.

Comment: What I am doing is just getting the info from the author like this: <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) , 75 ); ?> for the image. Now what I would need is to get the link to Linkedin added on the user contact info...

Comment: What i meant is your code to create linked in field on profile. i used this before `$profile_fields['link'] = 'Special Link';` and i can obtain it by the means of `<?php echo $author->link; ?>` and use this to get author `<?php $author = get_the_author(); ?>`